# Cannot find Plesk Server operating system version

Tags: webserver, web, plesk

Plesk screenshot:

[image: Plesk screenshot]

I'm hosting a website using Plesk 18.0.58, and I can't seem to find the server OS version no matter where i accessed. Does anyone know how? Attached is the Plesk screenshot that I currently have

I've tried going through most sections in the Plesk dashboard and checked using the SSH console, but it seems that the server OS version still doesn't seem to appear.

I've also tried looking for the Tools and settings option, but it doesn't seem to appear